# How do I reference Microsoft.CSharp in a Portable Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to use .NET 4's dynamic type in a Portable Class Library, but I'm having trouble getting all the required references working. I can reference System.Core just fine, but Microsoft.CSharp is giving me some trouble. It seems like I need to add all the different versions of Microsoft.CSharp.dll as references to my project, but Visual Studio is allowing me to add only one; if I add another, I get an error saying that it's already referenced. I can't  compile with just one of them, though - if I reference the Windows one, I get:

Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember'

when I try to build the project. And if I reference the Silverlight one, the reference seems to be invalid for some reason - it has a yellow warning icon it in the reference list in Solution Explorer!

So is there any way I can reference both of these DLL's without breaking my project or converting it to a non-portable library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a portable library that utilizes the [`dynamic` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) in .NET 4.0.

[Support for dynamic types in portable libraries was added in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx#assemblies).

In .NET 4.0, you'll have to resort to using Reflection in order to make the calls that you want to make (if you can't upgrade to 4.5).

Comment: Wow, seriously? I thought portable libraries were just a convenience, not a special type of library that required new framework code...

Comment: @ekolis It's not that it requires new framework code, but portable libraries were libraries which allowed a limited number of references.  With `dynamic`, it requires additional assemblies which probably had to be vetted to be suitable for portability (and *some* framework code, but not a ton).

Comment: Hmm, so there's no way to build a "semi-portable" library that includes most of what you need, and references whatever special bits are needed to finish it off?

Comment: @ekolis No, you'd need to have other assemblies that contain the "special" bits.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the purpose of this library involves dynamic objects... :(